# tab fragment not calling OnCreateView switching from tab1 to tab0?

Tags: android, android-fragments

There is three tab fragment in my app when tab at index 0 onCreate called when app launch, tab ta index 1 onCreateView method not called. I need to update UI in tab 1 onCreate method. How do i resolve this kind of issue.

code:

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    adapter.addFragment(new Users());
    adapter.addFragment(new FavouriteUsers());
    adapter.addFragment(new Recent());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

page Adapter code:

```
public class UserPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

public UserPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
    super(manager);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragmentList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentList.size();
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
}
}
```

Comment: are you using Viewpager with tablayout?

Comment: yes.................

Answer (score 1):

Try to Use getChildFragmentManager() to initilize your UserPagerAdapter

```
UserPagerAdapter adapter = new UserPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager())
```

if this doesn't work try changing FragmentStatePagerAdapter to **FragmentPagerAdapter**.

Answer (score 0):

implement  your `getItem(int position)` like this.

```
 @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Users tab1 = new Users();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                FavouriteUsers tab2 = new FavouriteUsers();
                return tab2;
            case 2:
                Recent tab3 = new Recent();
                return tab3;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
```

and in your tab activity call adapter like this

```
final UserPagerAdapter adapter = new UserPagerAdapter 
                (getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }     
            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }    
            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: but i have problem in

Comment: mTabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(view);
        mTabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
        mTabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);

Comment: for more about [Read this](http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/)